# Crystal function gets not waiting for user input

Tags: crystal-lang

The gets function in crystal is not waiting for user input. When I start my console application it immediately outputs an error like the one below. It is saying that the second parameter given to the in_array function is Nil but the program doesn't even ask for user input.

[image]

My code looks like below.

```
# Only alice and bob are greeted.
def in_array(array : Array, contains : String)
    array.each { |e|
        if e == contains
            return true;
        end
    }

    return false;
end

allowed = ["Alice", "Bob"]

puts "Please enter your name to gain access."
name = gets

isAllowed = in_array(allowed, name)

if isAllowed
    puts "You can enter the secret room"
else
    puts "You are not allowed to enter the secret room."
end
```

The new version of my code using includes? and read_line

```
# Only alice and bob are greeted.
allowed = ["Alice", "Bob"]

puts "Please enter your name to gain access."

name = read_line.chomp

if allowed.includes?(name)
    puts "You can enter the secret room"
else
    puts "You are not allowed to enter the secret room."
end
```

But when I enter Bob into the name variable the includes? method returns false and executes the else statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

1. The error you are seeing is a compile error. This means that your program is not running, it failed to compile.
2. `gets` can return `nil` (as indicated in the [docs](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.19.4/IO.html#gets%28limit%3AInt%29%3AString%7CNil-instance-method)), for example if the user presses Ctrl+C, so you have to handle this. You can either do `if name = gets`, use `gets.not_nil!` if you don't care about this case, or use `read_line` which is equivalent to `gets.not_nil!`
3. Array has a method `includes?` that does what you are trying to implement

Comment: 1. Ok so when the compiler detects an error it will stop compiling and you need to fix the error this is now clear to me. 2. I changed the gets function to read_line, I did puts the name variable and it showed me the name I did put in. 3. Yes the in_array function is exactly the same as includes? I changed it now but it still isn't working properly because when I put in the name Bob which is in the allowed array is says false and then executes the else. I updated my code with my new version

Comment: `gets` and `read_line` include the trailing newline, you need to invoke `chomp` to remove it